# Formula based on Roles Hierarichie

Tags: formula, formula-field

I would like to create a formula that is based on role hierarchies.
If I have the following Hierarchie:

- Agent 1

  - Agent 1.1
  - Agent 1.2

    - Agent 1.2.1
  - Agent 1.3
  - Agent 1.4
- Agent 2

I want to create a formula that checks if the current user is below the Agent 1 and on multiple levels. So if I am logged as user Agent 1.2.1 or 1.2 then I should get True but if I am logged as Agent 2 then it should be false

I tried `IF($UserRole.DeveloperName <='Agent1', 'True', False)`
It seems to work on one level but not more that one. So for Agent 1.2 it will return true but for 1.2.1 it will give False
Any idea ?

Comment: This can't be done with formula expressions. If your hierarchy is "small", you can brute force this via enumeration

Comment: IF(OR($UserRole.DeveloperName <='Agent1',$UserRole.DeveloperName <='Agent1.2), 'True', False) Try with this.